# Adding an iteration to a text file in a batch file

Tags: batch-file, iteration

I am trying to add an iteration to a text file to save the output number instead of it being overwritten to keep the iterations.
I am able to write the first iteration number but it will not add the number after.

I have a text file with just the iteration number as `1`.

**iteration.txt**
`1`

My batch code looks like this so far.

```
REM Run model outputs

set "iter="
for /F "delims=" %%i in (iteration.txt) do if not defined iter set "iter=%%i"
copy .\run1_Diagnostics.csv storefilesfolder\%itera%_Diagnostics.csv

echo %iter%+1 >iteration.txt
```

The problem is it either just overwrite the text file to +1 or +1 +1 +1 +1 and doesn't add the number.

Comment: batch isn't a real program *language*. There is nothing like `%var% +1` The only method to do math is [set /a](https://ss64.com/nt/set.html). You have to do the math with `set /a iter+=1` and then `echo %iter`.

Comment: I guess `%itera%` is a typo?

Comment: Yes it was a typo, I was able to make it work thank you.

Comment: please don't change your question to a wroking code. It invalidates both your question (which isn't a question anymore) and any answers. (Rolled back)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest to use this code:

```
REM Run model outputs

if not exist iteration.txt set "iter=1" & goto CopyFile

set "iter="
for /F "delims=" %%i in (iteration.txt) do if not defined iter set "iter=%%i"
set /A iter+=1

:CopyFile
copy run1_Diagnostics.csv storefilesfolder\%iter%_Diagnostics.csv
>iteration.txt echo %iter%
```

There is also another method to read the first line of a text file and assign it to an environment variable:

```
REM Run model outputs

if not exist iteration.txt set "iter=1" & goto CopyFile

set "iter="
set /P iter=<iteration.txt
set /A iter+=1

:CopyFile
echo copy run1_Diagnostics.csv storefilesfolder\%iter%_Diagnostics.csv
>iteration.txt echo %iter%
```

Both batch files first check if the file `iteration.txt` exists at all in current directory.

The environment variable `iter` is defined with value `1` if the file does not exist.

Otherwise the first line is read from the file and assigned to environment variable `iter` using command **FOR** or an input redirection from file on prompting for value of the environment variable using command **SET** with option `/P`.

The value read from file is incremented by one using command **SET** with option `/A` which means the new value of environment variable `iter` is the result of an arithmetic expression. `set /A` is the only method supported by Windows command line interpreter to do simple mathematical or binary operations on 32-bit signed integer values. The value of `iter` is `1` if the string read from file is not a valid 32-bit signed integer.

Next the file is copied with using initial value `1` or the value read from file `iteration.txt` incremented by one.

`.\` is not really necessary to specify the current directory. It is safe to omit those two characters if the file or folder is in current directory.

The last command line outputs the current iteration value to handle **STDOUT** which is redirected to file being created or overwritten in case of existing already.

The redirection operator and the file name is specified here left to command **ECHO** which outputs the number because of `echo %iter%>iteration.txt` would not work for the numbers `1` to `9`. And using `echo %iter% >iteration.txt` writes the space character between number and redirection operator `>` also into the file as trailing space which should be avoided here.

For understanding the used commands and how they work, open a command prompt window, execute there the following commands, and read entirely all help pages displayed for each command very carefully.

- `copy /?`
- `echo /?`
- `for /?`
- `goto /?`
- `if /?`
- `rem /?`
- `set /?`

Read also the Microsoft article about [Using Command Redirection Operators](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490982.aspx) for an explanation of redirection operators `<` and `>` and [single line with multiple commands using Windows batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25344009/3074564) for an explanation of operator `&`.